# Redirect to page 2 after comment

Tags: comments, pagination, redirect, read-more, split

I would like to have commenters going to the page 2 of a paginated post. My posts are separated by the `<!--more-->` tag so i have the `www.site.com/post-title` and `www.site.com/post-title/2/`. I want users to visit the second part of the post after commenting.

I found other questions explaining how to move the user to the paginated comment, that is `www.site.com/post-title/comment-page-x/#comment-x` but not to other pages of a paginated post.

**Edit:**
My site has the common setting for permalink that is `wpinstallation/%postname%/`. When paginated, it becomes `/%postname%/2/` for page 2.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a Regex what you are showing. Do you know how that works? Also: please [edit] your question and add _exactly_ how your paginated permalinks and how default permalinks (page 1/n) look like.

Comment: hi @kaiser Thanks for the reply, I have no idea how Regex work, I just found it on another forum as solution to another problem. I added the information of my permalinks structure, it is exactly as I mentioned on the post.

Comment: You can't just take some code from somewhere and repost/own it. Please add a link to the source and to the license. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to _remove_ the code. Just add a link to the source and state the license :)

Comment: @kaiser it was posted originally here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/a-simple-redirect-using-comment_post_redirect-in-functionsphp?replies=7 I couldn't find a specific license for the official Wordpress forum, but I presume would be the same as the whole Wordpress, and as it is stated at the bottom of that page, GPLv2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading a bit on regex and preg, starting from a previous example of a [similar problem](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/a-simple-redirect-using-comment_post_redirect-in-functionsphp?replies=7) and [testing it](http://www.regexr.com/39sba) I was able to answer my own question.

I added this function to functions.php:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: WPSE (#167237) Redirect after comment */

add_filter('comment_post_redirect', 'redirect_after_comment');
function redirect_after_comment($location)
{
    return preg_replace("/comment-page-([\d]+)\/#comment-([\d]+)/", "2", $location);
}
```

It's replacing the part of the url stating the comment page and comment anchor with "2". It may not be the cleanest solution but it's how I managed to do as a beginner.